# Why isn't background image for second div showing?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, prototype, jsfiddle

This is the prototype I am trying to implement [image]

Here is JsFiddle of what I have so far :  [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lasred/4wtaj9h7/)

What I am trying to do is make the options-Pick a Spending Profile, Find me suitable cards, etc have a background color. I tried doing this from the div that all of these options are in. Here is my code(from JS Fiddle) for doing so

```
#options {
      margin-top:20px;
      background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/EuMb532.png");
}
```

For some reason, using the same background image link, the header div was able to pick up the background color but my second div(enclosing all the options) wasn't able to.

I know that this wasn't a specifying class issue because I checked my syntax on [CSS Class](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp) and not an issue with the background image because it worked with the div header and I checked my syntax on [CSS Background](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp).

Does anyone know why the second div isn't showing the background color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the .To_Left spans inside #options are floated left, and #options is not styled to contain them, so they break out of #options and leave #options w/ no height.

Adding “overflow: hidden” (and probably a bottom margin) to #options will make the background show up.

Comment: Would you recommend floating these elements or doing the in line approach?

Comment: Personally, I would make them inline…

Answer (score 0):

You may have to remove the float property and use inline-block as follows:

```
.To_Left {
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
width:25%;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pqd72pns/)

One thing to be aware of is if you decide to use `inline-block` for your items; be sure to remove any extra white-space in your HTMl otherwise `width:25%;` will not work as your contents will add up to more than 100%.